# Async Ping PingComplete only in Console firing

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, console

I ran into a problem with a async ping. The static methode should send 10 pings to the network. After that the waiter is waiting until all answers are there. I decrement the activepings in the PingComplete methode.

```
public static List<string> Scanner()
{
    PingOptions Opt = new PingOptions(1, true);
    byte[] pingdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abababababababababababababababab");
    SpinWait waiter = new SpinWait();

    for (int i = 10; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        Ping.PingCompleted += Complete;
        lock (l)
        {
            activepings++;
        }

        ping.SendAsync(192.168.0. + i, 2000, pingdata, Opt);
    }

    while (activepings > 0)
    {
        waiter.SpinOnce();
    }
}
```

Here is the event-methode:

```
private static void Complete(object s, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (l)
    {
        activepings -= 1;
    }
}
```

If I call this methode in a normal console application it works great. But in a WPF or WinForms application the PingComplete event never fires. I have no idea whats wrong here. No response mean i am hanging all the time at my waiter.

**EDIT:**
Solved it similar to the postet problem. Started the code in a Thread like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29. Working fine. Thanks for helping!

Comment: where are you creating the Eventhandler in your winforms.. take a look at this previously posted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766953/asynchronous-code-that-works-in-console-but-not-in-windows-forms

Comment: I have no Eventhandler in my winform. Its all in one static class.

Comment: See the above link. It's exactly the same issue.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. But if you are calling the `Scanner()` method in your UI thread, commenter Ivan Stoev is correct; you have exactly the same problem as described (and answered) in the duplicate question. If you believe you have a different problem than that, provide a proper code example, along with a clear explanation for how your scenario is not the same.