# Execute Async Task Works in Console App but Not on WinForms App

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a console app which works fine.  Snippet:

```
//  do something
Execute(args, args...)
//  check response...

static async Task Execute(args, args...)
{
    // do stuff
    response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

But when I move this code to a WinForms app, it blocks main thread and never completes.

Is there any easy way to solve this?

Thanks...

Comment: How do you verify main thread is blocked by this method?

Comment: Incomplete. How do you call this in the WinForms app?

Comment: Seems blocked because app is frozen, plus this article leads me to believe it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766953/asynchronous-code-that-works-in-console-but-not-in-windows-forms)

Comment: I didn't want to include complete code, but in button click event, I gather data, build parameters, call Execute method.  Execute method does some setup and sends email via above line of code.  Email does get sent, but the await never returns control.  Don't understand why the downvotes, the question seems clear enough. Just want to know if there is technique that works on winforms app as well as it works in console app.

Comment: With async/await the whole call-stacj is involved, so you left out a crucial part. Consider writng a [mcve]

Comment: So 3 downvotes now. Guess I really need to learn how to ask a question here.  It's a tough house.  Thanks anyway for the constructive criticism. Would have been nice to get some insight into the cause of the problem. I did some more googling and found the solution myself.

Comment: Google for "async turtles"

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with more research.  Winforms app seems to act considerably different than console app in the way it handles async calls.  Instead of

```
async Task TaskName()
{
    await AsyncMethod
}
```

This is what worked:

```
    private async Task<T> TaskName(args, args, args...)
    {
        return await Task<T>.Run(async () =>
        {
            // code here with await call to async method
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe Task.Run is the solution but that's not clear. And when it is then this is over complicating things.

Comment: Fair enough, but I've found more than one SO article which says this is the way to avoid blocking on WinForms app.  In the absence of any actual suggestion on this thread, I guess I'm stuck with that.